# How to use page-break in react?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I wanna use page-break because I wanna use when i print my page.

Now, code is no error and no warning. but i can't separate page.

Is it different method in react?

This is my code.

```js
//...
    for(let row = 0; row < rowCount; row++) {
    //some code
    //...
    //...
      page.push(
        <table key={`tablePage.'${row}`} >
          <tbody >
            <tr>
              {part}
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      );
      page.push(<div key={`brPage.'${row}`} styleName='page-divide'></div>);
    }
    return page;
```

```css
@media print {
  .page-divide {
    page-break-after: always;
    page-break-beforer: always;
  }
}
```

Comment: styleName is not a valid attribute AFAIK. Should be className I think. Also you have a typo in your CSS, it should be page-break-before

Comment: Did you try `<br />` ?

Comment: Of course i tried br tag. but Is not fundamental solution.  I mean that is not working as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you incorrectly use use the "styleName",it should be

```
page.push(<div key={`brPage.'${row}`} className='page-divide'></div>);
```

Comment: Of course, I tried className but also is not working.